# Reading some NOMADS grib files fails

Tags: python, grib, grib-2

I am trying to read in a file from `https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov`

I can read all multigrid files like [here](https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/wave/prod/multi_1.20201113/)

but my script fails to read files from other links that are supposed to be Grib files
such as files from [here](https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/estofs/prod/estofs_pac.20201113/)
and fails with the error below

```
Exception has occurred: exceptions.ValueError
no matches found
  File "/buio/buio/pygrib.pyx", line 610, in pygrib.open.select
```

or from [here](http://www.globalmarinenet.com/free-grib-file-downloads/#download)

I use [this](https://polar.ncep.noaa.gov/waves/examples/usingpython.shtml) python script to read the files.
I guess the format must be different?

Comment: Have you tried `rioxarray.open_rasterio`?

Comment: Hi there, no, I have not looked into this further. Thanks, I'll check the library.